# Error while executing save command in R

Tags: r

Just for practice purpose i was trying to use save command in RStudio and it goes in the following way:

```
> n<-20

> r<-1:10

> w<-data.frame(n,r)
> n
[1] 20
> r
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> w
    n  r
1  20  1
2  20  2
3  20  3
4  20  4
5  20  5
6  20  6
7  20  7
8  20  8
9  20  9
10 20 10
> save(n,r,w,file="data/multiple.rdata")
```

After executing the above save command i get the following error:

```
Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
cannot open compressed file 'data/multiple.rdata', probable reason 'No such     
file or directory'
```

What should i do?

Comment: the documentation suggest that one of the reasons could be **lack of write permission in the current directory**. Can you try saving to a different location, check if `data` folder exists

Comment: yeah it's either that or simply that you didn't properly provide the path. Try using the full path.